# How can I easily package PEAR dependencies with app?

Tags: php, pear

I am working on a PHP application which leverages some PEAR packages. I want to be able to package the app in archive (e.g. tar, zip, etc) to be easily downloaded and extracted on servers to run. I do not want the servers to need PEAR for downloading or installing the dependencies. Is there a simple way of packaging the PEAR dependencies with the application?

Comment: Have you tried to make the application a pear package, too and define the dependencies?

Comment: How would someone get the app's pear package with all its dependencies without using pear?I am not very experienced with pear beyond using it to occasionally get some packages.

Comment: One would not. But as pear is needed for your dependencies anyway, this would not be a problem, right?

Comment: It is. I don't mind pear on a development machine, but I can't expect it to be on the runtime environments.

Comment: Than create yourself a build task and package your application with all dependencies so that pear is not needed on the target machines.

Comment: And my question is asking is there anything out there already which will do this build task for me so I do not have to do it all by hand myself. If there something already out there which do so, there is no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: sure, one of those build tools is phing - http://www.phing.info/trac/wiki/Users/Download - others are ant or gnu make.

Comment: But is there anything which packages those dependencies without me needing to look them up by myself, then pull them in together. Phing doesn't have a task which pulls PEAR dependencies into a single dir conveniently. If you're familiar with the Java world, think maven. There's a maven plugin for php but it doesn't leverage PEAR. As a result, most of its packages are out of date.

Comment: Okay, you are probably looking for [Composer, a tool for dependency management in PHP](http://getcomposer.org/). If I now understand you correctly, this should do what you want.

Comment: That looks more like what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you are probably looking for [Composer, a tool for dependency management](http://www.getcomposer.org/) in PHP.

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deploy (I recommend you provide both options):

1. Phar
2. Expanded Directory of Files

In either case, if you are going to be harvesting all of the dependent component files, you can query PEAR for these.

**List packages installed by the PEAR installer**

```
pear list
```

**Resulting List**

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7   stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.0   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

**List files for package XML_Util**

```
pear list-files Archive_Tar # or pear list Archive_Tar
```

**Resulting List**

```
Installed Files For Archive_Tar
===============================
Type Install Path
php  /Users/wilmoore/local/php/versions/5.4.0/lib/php/Archive/Tar.php
doc  /Users/wilmoore/local/php/versions/5.4.0/lib/php/doc/Archive_Tar/docs/Archive_Tar.txt
```

From here, it is simply a matter of iterating over that list and harvesting the files. You should be able to skip the lines prefixed with "doc".

Comment: Nothing which does the second option already? I'll need to write a custom script to do it for me??